# Is it possible to give html images more than one fallback url?

Tags: javascript, html

I found out that you can have a fallback URL for an `<img>` using `onerror` if the first loading fails.

But it is possible to provide a list of sources (urls) to try and keep trying until one of them loads?

I was messing around with this for about an hour and was working towards this solution with JavaScript. I think its very clunky and I wonder if there is more more pretty way of doing this.

**My ugly approach**

Each image has several data attributes such as `fallback1`, `fallback2` with the alternatives sources to load from if loading fails. Every image also has `this.onerror=null;this.src='error.jpg`
So every image that fails to load will show the picture `error.jpg` instead.

So an image may look like this

`<img src="https://i.imgur.com/iYNdJeW.jpg" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='error.jpg'" data-fallback1="https://i.imgur.com/iYNdJeW2.jpg" data-fallback2="https://i.imgur.com/iYNdJeW3.jpg" />`

Call a script in `window.onload` that iterates over each image and check if the source ends with `error.jpg`.

If it does it takes the first fallback url in that image's data properties (fallback1) and changes the source to that. Then removes that data-property from the image (not sure if that is possible or meant to be done), because he has already been tried. Then the script recursively runs again.

The recursion stops if if no images' source ends in `error.jpg` OR If all images whose source ends with `error.jpg` do not have any data attributes (no more alternative sources to try).

I think it would work, but it seem very very hackish.

I found out about `<picture>` and `<source>` and was very optimistic, but `<picture>` just accepts a 404 if the image does not load.

Has anyone come up with a better approach for doing this? Ideally I wish you could give `img` a list of urls and it would just keep trying until it got a non-error.

Comment: I personally think that this is not a good practice in the mobile area. Trying to load an image with a bad connection and doing this same mistake multiple times, is not logical.

Answer (score 4):

You're setting `onerror` to null when your first error is fired. Onerror will automatically fire if you change the source and it fails to load again. You could just store the list of fallbacks and increment an index each time onerror is fired.

Here's an example, and you could easily convert this to store all of the different variables directly on the element. I've provided 4 fake URLs and a final placeholder image as a real URL. You'll see it does load the placeholder image.

```js
var fallbacks = ["https://example.com/badurl1.jpg", "https://example.com/badurl2.jpg", "https://example.com/badurl3.jpg", "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"];
var index = 0;

document.querySelector("img").onerror = function(){
  if(index >= fallbacks.length) return;
  let next = fallbacks[index];
  this.src = next;
  index++;
};
```

```html
<img src="https://example.com/badurl.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will cycle through a list until your image stops getting an error
to edit it, change the 'fallbacksrc' array
HTML

```
<img src="*" id="img" onerror="ImgOnError()"></img>
```

JS

```
let fallbacksrc=[]; //All All Fallbacks Here, when error will start at the second one because 1st one is already tried
let fallbackcount = 1;
let Img = document.getElementById('img')
function ImgOnError(){
    if(fallbackcount >= fallbacksrc.length){
        fallbackcount = 0
        Img.src=fallbacksrc[fallbackcount]
    }else{
        Img.src=fallbacksrc[fallbackcount]
    }
    fallbackcount++;
}
```

Comment: you've just created a never ending bad request.

Comment: @Nora still erroring out to this day...

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a vanilla-JavaScript way where you don't need to specify the image in javascript.

Define this function:

```js
function incrementFallbackSrc(img, srcs) {
    if (typeof img.fallbackSrcIndex === 'undefined') img.fallbackSrcIndex = 0;
    img.src = srcs[img.fallbackSrcIndex++];
}
```

and for each image, pass all the fallback URLs in the function call.

```html
<img
src="https://i.imgur.com/iYNdJeW.jpg"
onerror="javascript:  incrementFallbackSrc(this, ['https://i.imgur.com/iYNdJeW2.jpg',
'https://i.imgur.com/iYNdJeW3.jpg',
'error.jpg'])">
>
```

to set it programmatically, you may have to put the function inside the definitiaion like so:

```js
img.setAttribute('onerror', "function incrementFallbackSrc(img, srcs) {if (typeof img.fallbackSrcIndex === 'undefined') img.fallbackSrcIndex = 0;img.src = srcs[img.fallbackSrcIndex++];}; incrementFallbackSrc(this, ['" + fallbackUrl1 + "," + fallbackUrl2 + "'])");
```